# JAVA: conversion from 64bit fpn to decimal

Tags: java, binary, ieee-754

I am having trouble converting this java code...the code originally converts 32bit fpn to decimal. I am trying to make it covert 64bit fpn to decimal. Please help

**original code that converts 32bit FPN to decimal**

---

```
private void ConvertToDecimal(){
    int pos = 1;
    double doubleBin [] = new double [FPNRep.length()];
    boolean bNegative = false;
    double exp = 0.0;
    double sig = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i<=FPNRep.length() - 1; i++){
        if (FPNRep.charAt(i) == '0'){
            doubleBin[i] = 0;}
        else{
            doubleBin[i] = 1;}}

    if (doubleBin[0] == 1){
        bNegative = true;}
    else{
        bNegative = false;}
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++){
        exp += (doubleBin[i] * Math.pow(2, 8 - i));}
    exp = exp - 127;
    for (int i = 9; i <= 31; i++){
        if (doubleBin[i] == 1){
            sig  += (1 / Math.pow(2, pos));}
        pos++;}
    //Add the hidden bit.
    sig = sig + 1;
    if (bNegative == true){
        number = -1 * sig  * Math.pow(2, exp);}
    else{
        number = 1 * sig * Math.pow(2, exp);}
    return;
}
```

---

**my attempt to change the code to 64-bit FPN to decimal and my results**

---

```
private void ConvertToDecimal(){
    int pos = 1;
    double doubleBin [] = new double [FPNRep.length()];
    boolean bNegative = false;
    double exp = 0.0;
    double sig = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i<=FPNRep.length() - 1; i++){
        if (FPNRep.charAt(i) == '0'){
            doubleBin[i] = 0;}
        else{
            doubleBin[i] = 1;}}

    if (doubleBin[0] == 1){
            bNegative = true;}
    else{
            bNegative = false;}
    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++){
        exp += (doubleBin[i] * Math.pow(2, 11 - i));}
        exp = exp - 127;
    for (int i = 12; i <= 63; i++){
        if (doubleBin[i] == 1){
            sig  += (1 / Math.pow(2, pos));}
        pos++;}
        //Add the hidden bit.
        sig = sig + 1;
        if (bNegative == true){
            number = -1 * sig  * Math.pow(2, exp);}
        else{
            number = 1 * sig * Math.pow(2, exp);}
        return;
}
```

---

I used the 64-bit representation of 12 and these were my results after running my attempted 64-bit to decimal code:

```
result should = 12

result = 6.339534373627983E270
```

If you are unsure of what I am trying to do refer to [this website](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you go to the trouble of doing this all by hand where Java already has all the methods you want.

It looks like your input is a `String` representing a base 2 IEEE 754 floating point number in binary, either 32bit or 64bit. Coincidentally, this is exactly what Java's `float` and `double` are, respectively. Therefore:

```
public float binaryStringToFloat(final String input)
{
    return Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.parseInt(input, 2));
}

public double binaryStringToDouble(final String input)
{
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(Long.parseLong(input, 2));
}
```